Cognito - On Sign-in history, setting Event Valid does not unblock users who receive the "Unable to login because of security reasons" message
Advanced security is enabled on my Cognito with Adaptive authentication set to block high-risk sign-ins and notify users.
The user successfully logs in on Device A, connected to Network A and running OS A. However, when attempting to log in on Device B, connected to Network B and running OS B, Cognito recognizes it as a high-risk attempt and blocks the login. The user receives an "Unable to login because of security reasons" message, which is expected in such cases.
Now I'd like to unblock the user to access the app on Device B, Network B, and OS B. To do this, I go to Cognito and confirm the corresponding record at User Event History as a Valid Event.


After doing it, I expected that the next time the user tries to log in from Device B, Network B, and OS B, it would be allowed. However, it still always shows as blocked and displays the message "Unable to login because of security reasons".
To log in, the user needs to enter their login email and password. After that, a MFA code is sent to the user's email. The user will need to enter this code to complete the login process.
Notice that the App Client on this Cognito User Pool has the Authentication flow set to CUSTOM_AUTH_FLOW_ONLY, as it's required the MFA code be sent during the login process.
Heere is an example of success login.

Am I missing any additional steps?
Any advice would be appreciated.
